# Premake "no active solution, project or configuration" error

Tags: premake

I am trying to run premake with custom script like this

> premake4.exe -file=proj4_shared.lua vs2010

And I get

> proj4_shared.lua:2: no active solution, project, or configuration

Contens of the proj4_shared.lua:

```
#!lua
solution ("Proj4")
    project "proj4"
        language "C++"
        kind     "SharedLib"
        files  { "proj4/*.h", "src/src/*.c", "src/src/proj4.def" }
        excludes { "src/src/cs2cs.c", "src/src/geod.c", "src/src/nad2bin.c", "src/src/nad2nad.c" }
        location (BUILD_DIR .. "vcproj")
        includedirs { "src/src" }
        defines { "WIN32", "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" }
        buildoptions { "/W1" }

        local p = project()
        p.uuid = GetExistingUuid(p) or p.uuid

        configuration { "Debug*" }
            defines { "_DEBUG", "DEBUG" }
            flags   { "Symbols" }
            targetsuffix "D"

        configuration { "Release*" }
            defines { "NDEBUG" }
            flags   { "Optimize" }
            if (not DISABLE_RELEASE_SYMBOLS) then flags { "Symbols" } end
            targetsuffix ""
```

According to https://github.com/premake/premake-4.x/wiki/solution

> The solution function creates a new solution and makes it active

So what is the issue?

Comment: That script isn't complete. Where are `BUILD_DIR`, `GetExistingUuid` and `DISABLE_RELEASE_SYMBOLS` defined? When I remove all of that stuff I can generate project files with no issues. My guess is you've got a bunch of wrapper code around your example, and that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. This project was part of larger one. Those variables were defined in the "main" premake lua script.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try:

```
solution ("Proj4")
  local p = project "proj4"
  ...
```

I suspect the call to `project()` with no argument is confusing the system.

ALTERNATIVELY:

You can try:

```
local p = premake.api.current.project
```

Which should also work to get you a reference to the current project.

NOTE: I am using premake5.exe, not premake 4, so some things may have changed in the interim.

Comment: Hello Jesse, thanks for your answer. I no longer have the project check if it works though. Hope your answer helps someone :)